# Cayenne JOIN expression

Tags: postgresql, join, inner-join, apache-cayenne

I've been trying to do a join query with cayenne but I'm getting stuck with the use of Expressions and that.
In sql it would be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM usuarios, rol, user_rol
WHERE usuarios.cod_usuario = user_rol.cod_usuario
AND user_rol.cod_rol = rol.cod_rol
```

This would be the basic.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify before I can write an answer, is the goal to filter usuarios records to only those that are returned in the inner join or you just need to read these 3 tables together?

Comment: I need to return a specific value(permisos) of 'rol' table given an certain user(login) from 'user' table.
usuarios: cod_usuario, login, password
user_rol: cod_usuario, cod_rol
rol: cod_rol, permisos
If it's not possible to return that value in a direct way with cayenne I would satisfy with been able to read these tables together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to that, just like with [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086442/cayenne-postgres-primary-key-generation) that you had is to use relationships. Once you map the relationships between Usuarios / UserRol and UserRol / Rol, you can either traverse the relationship from the user object by calling its methods:

```
Usuarios u = ..
for(UserRol ur : u.getUserRols()) {
    Rol r = ur.getRol();
    // now do something with it
}
```

Or find Rols with a query matching that user:

```
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(Rol.class);
query.andQualifier(ExpressionFactory.matchExp("userRol.user", u);
List<Rol> roles = context.performQuery(query);
```

Path argument of 'ExpressionFactory.matchExp' (i.e. "userRol.user" String) should be adjusted to match the actual relationship names starting at the Rol entity (as Rol is the root of the query), going to UserRol, and from that to Usuarios.

Comment: I tried the first one and it worked but the second one gave an error "Can't resolve path component: [Rol.UserRol]." Could you tell me how does it work the method 'matchExp'?

Comment: So you have at least one solution already :) ... I'll expand the answer to clarify about the second option

Comment: Thanks. I'll be waiting for your response.

Comment: I already amended the answer by the time you posted your last comment.